# Can we reduce bzip2 block size lower than 100KB?

Tags: c, linux, compression, bzip2

Currently bzip2 uses the smallest block size for compression and decompression of 100KB (parameter -1). Can we reduce the block size easily in bzip, without deteriorating the performance much?

Is there any other implementation of bzip2 which does the same?

Comment: `bzip2`  is free software. Did you study its source code?

Comment: Yes, the block size can be changed using flags `-1(100kb to -9 (900kb)` but has an impact on performance.  See this http://www.bzip.org/1.0.3/html/memory-management.html

Comment: @pbu i asked for lower than 100kb.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I checked the code, but not in detail. I wanted to know if there is any technical constraint or performance degradation issue with changing the source code for block size smaller than 100K.

Comment: **Why do you ask?** (please edit your question to improve it!). Perhaps `bzip2` is not the right compression tool in your case... Did you consider the less efficient but faster `gzip` and/or using the [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) library?

Comment: I think you can, if you modify source code, which is simple, imo. But decoder out there are hard coded for 1 to 9, so, I dont think it will compatible for existing decoders.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd use the parallel version of `bzip2`. It's compatible with the original `bzip2` and it really does speed things up tremendously.

```
http://compression.ca/pbzip2/
```

You can then change the block size and you performance is still likely to beat the non parallel `bzip2`.